# How can I use my vintage Canon FD lenses on a digital camera?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount, old-lenses

I'd like to use a few vintage Canon FD lenses. I have a few telephotos and a fish eye in absolute perfect optical condition. They sit on a shelf.

[From this post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21934/mount-old-lens-on-canon-rebel-t3i-using-canon-fd-fl-lens-to-canon-eos-ef-body-mo), I understand I can't simply get a universal adapter and shoot on a Canon EOS mount.

Are there individual mounts available or a different make model camera (digital) that is compatible?

Comment: related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/7172/35348

Comment: SONY NEX-_  e-mount lens cameras will (almost certainly) mount these with an adaptor. Check eg ebay for availability. NEX3 are 'good' and lowish cost. NEX5T is superb, 5N is almost as good. Below that is very acceptable but less good in various ways. .

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to the question you linked already explains your situation pretty well (that it is hard to adapt FD lenses to an EOS camera due to difference in sensor distance).

> Are there individual mounts available or a different make model camera
>   (digital) that is compatible?

Any mirrorless camera from any brand should have no problem to use FD lenses using a simple mechanical adapter. Because they don't have a mirror the sensor distance will always be shorter than the FD mount.

So if you pick a camera like this (Panasonic, Sony, Olympus) you should be able to use your FD lenses. At the time of writing Sony is the only company that offers full frame mirrorless - the A7 series - (so that you can take advantage of the full area of the lens). Another good option is the micro 4/3 mount (but it uses only the center half of the lens)

Even Canon offers a mirrorless camera now (1.6 crop factor) that could use FD lenses (that is fairly new and I am not sure about the adapters).